# Java maze inside of walls and get all possible paths

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array, text-files, maze

I know that there's a lot of other maze solver here. Though I would like to have my own approach and I think my problem is a bit different from the others.

As of now, here's what I've started and hopefully I can achieve what I have in mind at the moment.

```
    private static int getPossiblePaths(File f) throws IOException {

    int counts = 0; // hope to return all possible paths

    // read input file then put it on list string
    List<String> lines = Files.lines(f.toPath()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    // get the row and column (dimensions)
    String[] dimensions = lines.get(0).split(",");

    //initalize sub matrix of the maze dimensions and ignoring the top and bottom walls
    int[][] mat = new int[Integer.valueOf(dimensions[0]) - 2 ][Integer.valueOf(dimensions[1]) - 2];    

    //for each line in the maze excluding the boundaries (top and bottom)
    for( int i = 2 ; i < lines.size() - 1  ; i++) {
        String currLine = lines.get(i);
        int j = 0; 
        for(char c : currLine.toCharArray()) {
            mat[i-2][j] = (c=='*' ? 'w' : c=='A' ? 'a' : c=='B' ? 'b' : 's');

            // some conditional statements here

        }  
    }
// or maybe some conditional statements here outside of the loop

    return counts;

}
```

And the maze from a text file is look like this. Please note that the A could be anywhere and same as B. The only movements allowed is to **right** and **down**.

```
5,5
*****
*A  *
*   *
*  B*
*****
```

Expected output for the maze above is 6 (possible paths from A to B).

EDIT: Also the maze from the text file could be like this:

```
8,5
********
* A    *
*     B*
*      *
********
```

So with my current code, it is getting the dimensions (first line) and removing the top and bottom part of the maze (boundaries). So there's only 3 lines of characters currently stored in the **mat** array. And some encoding of each characters of the text file (#=w(wall), A=a(start), B=b(end), else s(space))

I would like to have some conditional statements inside of the foreach to probably store the each of characters inside of an ArrayList. Though I'm not sure if this approach will just make my life harder.

Any suggestions, tips, advice or other easier approach from you guys will greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Start by marking the *end* with a 1, all fields next to it with a 2... until you reach the start. Then every shortest path goes always 1 down.

Comment: The second example has the dimensions specified in colums/rows order, but your code interprets them in the opposite sense. Also, your code tests for `#` for finding a wall, but your input examples use `*` for walls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea to create `mat` is fine. I would not bother to strip off the first and last line, as in fact it will be easier to work with when you keep them. That way a row reference like `i-1` will not go out of range when you are at a non-wall location.

I would also not store characters like `w` in there, but specific numbers, like -1 for wall, 0 for free. Also store 0 for "A" and "B". When encountering those two letters, you could store their coordinates in specific variables (e.g. `rowA`, `colA`, `rowB`, `colB`). You may need to check whether B is down-right from A, as otherwise B is certainly not reachable from A.

So I would define `mat` as follows (note that I reversed the dimensions, because your second example demonstrates that the first line of the input has them in that order):

```
    int[][] mat = new int[Integer.valueOf(dimensions[1])]
                         [Integer.valueOf(dimensions[0])];

    int colA = mat[0].length;
    int rowA = 0;
    int colB = colA;
    int rowB = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        String currLine = lines.get(i+1);
        int j = 0;
        for (char c : currLine.toCharArray()) {
            mat[i][j] = c == '*' ? -1 : 0;
            if (c == 'B') {
                if (colA > j) return 0; // B unreachable from A
                rowB = i;
                colB = j;
            } else if (c == 'A') {
                if (colB < j) return 0; // B unreachable from A
                rowA = i;
                colA = j;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
```

With this setup you can reuse `mat` to store the number of paths from A to the current position. The value 0 at `A` should be set to 1 (there is one path from A to A), and then it is a matter of adding up the value from the cell above and left, making sure that -1 is treated as a 0.

```
    mat[rowA][colA] = 1;
    for (int i = rowA; i <= rowB; i++) {
        for (int j = colA; j <= colB; j++) {
            if (mat[i][j] == 0) { // not a wall?
                // count the number of paths that come from above,
                //   plus the number of paths that come from the left
                mat[i][j] = Math.max(0, mat[i-1][j]) + Math.max(0, mat[i][j-1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return mat[rowB][colB]; // now this has the number of paths we are looking for
```

Although a recursive method will also work, I would suggest the above *dynamic programming* approach, since that way you avoid to recalculate counts for a certain cell several times (when coming there via different DFS paths). This solution has a linear time complexity.

Comment: I'm getting **IndexOutofBounds** as well from this line => `mat[i][j] = Math.max(0, mat[i-1][j]) + Math.max(0, mat[i][j-1]);` I'm trying to adjust my code accordingly, and I'm using your approach as my reference.

Comment: For this line to work, you must not delete the original first/last rows, and the input must define a maze that has `#` all around the border. If this condition is not met, then you'll get the index-out-of-bounds error.

Comment: I didn't actually delete the original first/last rows. Somehow it's still showing index-out-of-bounds error :(. I'm only getting the error if I put the other combination of maze (edited above).

Comment: Do you get it with the input that you specified in the question, or with some other maze?

Comment: Sorry I just edited my comment to you, yes I'm getting the error if I choose to use the other maze like the 2nd above. Also I don't get the **6** expected output from the first maze using your approach.

Comment: Let me make a fiddle which you can run, which will run on both those inputs. Hold on...

Comment: I had to fix a few issues (`j++`, `.get(i+1)`, single quotes, asterisk instead of hash, and reversal of the dimensions). I updated my answer accordingly. See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/MazeWithDownLeftOnly)

Comment: This solution is so good! It opened my eyes with dynamic programming. Thanks for explaining everything! I think the critical part for me was having some variables to store the coordinates when it encounters A and B. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I propose a simple recursion with 2 calls: down and right.

This is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JavaMazeInsideOfWallsAndGetAllPossiblePaths {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        Path mazePath = Paths.get( MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getClassLoader()
                  .getResource("maze.txt").toURI());
        File mazeFile = mazePath.toFile();
        System.out.println(getPossiblePaths(mazeFile));

    }

    private static int getPossiblePaths(File f) throws IOException {
        // read input file then put it on list string
        List<String> lines = Files.lines(f.toPath()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // get the row and column (dimensions)
        String[] dimensions = lines.get(0).split(",");

        //initalize sub matrix of the maze dimensions and ignoring the top and bottom walls
        int[][] mat = new int[Integer.valueOf(dimensions[0]) - 2 ][Integer.valueOf(dimensions[1]) - 2];

        int fromRow = -1, fromCol = -1, toRow = -1, toCol = -1;

        for( int i = 2 ; i < lines.size() - 1  ; i++) {
            String currLine = lines.get(i);
            int j = 0;
            for(char c : currLine.toCharArray()) {
                switch(c) {
                case '*':
                    continue; // for loop
                case 'A':
                    mat[i-2][j] = 0;
                    fromRow = i-2;
                    fromCol = j;
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    mat[i-2][j] = 2;
                    toRow = i-2;
                    toCol = j;
                    break;
                default:
                    mat[i-2][j] = 1;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }

        return getPossiblePathsRecursive(mat, fromRow, fromCol, toRow, toCol);
    }

    private static int getPossiblePathsRecursive(int[][] mat, int i, int j, int rows, int columns) throws IOException {

        if(i > rows || j > columns) {
            return 0;
        }

        if(mat[i][j] == 2) {
            return 1;
        }

        return getPossiblePathsRecursive(mat, i+1, j, rows, columns) +
               getPossiblePathsRecursive(mat, i, j + 1, rows, columns);
    }
}
```

Notes:
1. The validation step is skipped (assuming that the input data is in a valid format)
2. The walls are ignored (assuming that there are always 4 walls - first row, last row, first column, last column. These walls are assumed to be represented as '*')

Comment: I'm getting out of bounds with this especially on this line `mat[i-2][j++] = (c=='A' ? 0 : c=='B' ? 2 : 1);` If the **A** is on the second column and if **B** is on 3rd row (instead of last row). I have edited my question to include the other format of a maze just in case.

Comment: With your part of notes *The walls are ignored (assuming that there are always 4 walls - first row, last row, first column, last column. These walls are assumed to be represented as '*')* I would really love to see how recursion works with this, and also with the second maze from the example that I've included to the edit above.

Comment: I've edited my answer, and fixed the index out of bound issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still getting index out of bound issue when it comes to the second maze that I've included above. :(